# iphone private API

Tags: iphone

is XCODE will show warning if we use private API in our Iphone application...?

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Xcode will not emit compiler warnings, however if you try to enter the name of a private method or class while coding, you'll notice that it doesn't trigger autocomplete as you type.

So you'll need to be more careful if you're developing for App Store distribution. You can check whether something is a private API either by consulting the documentation (if you can't find it, chances are it's private), or by asking on the developer forums or here.